# What is the best practice to create array notation fields in play-framework templates?

Tags: templates, playframework

In one of my Play! projects I use a table of inputs to update multiple objects in one go.

I pass it to the controller as an array of objects. This works quite well, but the template looks quite a mess, since I'm forced to write the whole array index notation.

The template in its current state:

```
#{list items:_articles, as:'article' }
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">${article.number}</a></td>
    <td>${article.name}</td>
    <td>${article.totalPrice}</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="${ 'articles[' + article_index + '].description'}" value="${article.description}" /></td>
    <td>
        #{select 'articles[' + article_index+ '].consignment', value:article.consignment}

            #{option ''} -- #{/option}
            #{option 'Foo'} Foo #{/option}
            #{option 'Bazz'} Bazz #{/option}
            #{option 'Bar'} Bar #{/option}
        #{/select}
           <input type="hidden" name="${ 'articles[' + article_index + '].id'}" value="${article.id}" /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
#{/list}
```

What - if there is one - is the best-practice to create array-notation fields using the play-framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a seperate variable for the `'articles[' + article_index + ']` inside your loop?

Or; Maybe you just can leave it out? Create an array without your article index:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article.id[]" />
<input type="text" name="article.name[]" />
```

Later on, in your loop you can figure out the array index, and the corresponding id. Problem is you can't have optional fields this way. I won't recommend it.